# Python for-loop query

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I am checking a piece of Python code I found online (http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/18305/), and I'm stuck trying to understand a seemingly simple for loop.

To be honest I don't know Python, but I have experience in other programming languages.

```
def _generatePayload(self, collisionchars, payloadlength):
    result = ""

    for item in collisionchars:
        result = result.replace(str(item), collisionchars[item])

    return result;
```

I have modified the code slightly to remove the parts that are irrelevant to the question, but I have retained the same method definition as found in the original source. As I understand this, it is replacing a string (within a char array / string) by another string which has the same value??

Thanks a bunch guys!

Comment: It might be, have you tried it to see what it does?

Comment: No. Unfortunately I don't have the luxury of Python installed on this machine, and I cannot install. If I could I would have tried it myself :)

Comment: Why we need to pass the variable payloadlength, since we don't use it anywehre in this function? Could you please post all the correspoding code, because it seems to me strange this fact. Thanks

Comment: @ChristosPaisios - That is not the whole code. I ommitted the parts that I found irrelevant to the question. However as I mentioned in the question, the original source is found at: http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/18305/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collisionchars` seems to be a dict (note the indexer).

What the code does is loop through all keys of `collisionchars`, and replace each occurence of that key in `result` with the value of that key.

So, if `collisionchars = {'a': 'X', 'o': '_'}` and `result = 'FooBar'`, the code would alter `result` to `F__BXr` (replacing each `a` with `X` and each `o` with `_`).

Comment: Thank you! If collisionchars is actually a dictionary, then the whole thing makes sense, but I cannot readily tell from the linked source code. However at one point a variable named hashes seems to be declared as a dictionary, so this would make sense. Also, thanks for the thoroughness in the answer. I'll wait a bit more, and then mark it as answer.

Comment: If you work your way through the script you linked you'll find the creation of the `dict` in the function `_computeCollisionChars`: `hashes = {}`. It's being populated in that function, returned, and finally passed to `_generatePayload`.

Comment: I actually did check out the code, but I think I lost track of the dictionary afterwards and assumed it was a string / char array. That makes perfect sense, now that I look at it again. Thanks for your time :)